# Why did this jQuery script stop working?

Tags: jquery

I have a drag and drop script which transfers a panel.

I was testing the script two days ago and it was working on all browsers, but now it doesn't work in Chrome:

```
$('.dragbox')
.each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).find('#sc-top-panel').addClass('collapse');
    }, function(){
    $(this).find('#sc-top-panel').removeClass('collapse');
    })
    .find('#sc-top-panel').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    })
    .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
        updateWidgetData();
    })
    .end()
    .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

This part doesn't work in Chrome:

```
    .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
```

The `updateWidgetData()` calls aren't being made. The other functions and operators don't work either.

**UPD:** Problem in .click function. Chrome can't process it. I tried substitute her. Eg, .bind('click'....); .live('click'....). It all doesn't work.

Comment: whats the error?  try web developer Mozilla plugin http://goo.gl/fNmKW

Comment: @Mohit: The Web Developer plugin is for Firefox, not Chrome.

Comment: Regardless, Chrome has the Web Inspector.

Comment: I tried watch in console of errors - there don't have errors and console of JAVA i don't can open. I can send all script on you email (it's very big).

Comment: I don't can find Web Inspector.

Comment: I updated Chrome to version 13 today. It's can be a problem?

Comment: You really need help - get [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) created.

Comment: Chrome performs auto-updates.  Maybe Chrome upgraded itself recently?

Comment: Right click on the window, and click inspect element (it doesn't really matter which element).  Look in the console and scripts tabs for bugs.  Also, I agree with Lobo, try to set up a fiddle for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the same script. I can't find out what has gone wrong but the script was working fine couple of days ago and then suddenly stopped working. The collapsible part is working fine(The script saves the states of collapsed/not collapsed) but the drag'n'drop isn't saved.

The script as a whole works well in IE and Mozilla, Chrome is the only browser that won't save the states. I haven't tested it in Safari.

Edit : I have fixed the script for my specific problem, don't know if it'll help others. Here is a part of the code :

```
        stop: function(event, ui){
        ui.item.css({'top':'0','left':'0'}); //Opera fix
        if(!$.browser.mozilla && !$.browser.safari)
            updateWidgetData();
```

I removed :

```
if(!$.browser.mozilla && !$.browser.safari)
```

and now It's working fine. I dont know why suddenly the code stopped working only in Chrome. Let me know if this problem is occurring for someone else.